# 2 Sum algorithm with Hashing C++

Tags: c++, hashmap

Question about my code (CPP)
HyungJun GuWeek 4 · 2 hours ago
I've written my programming assignment code and I think there are some problem.

Before I do original question, I tried sample exam to test whether my code is right or wrong.

The original problem is

The goal of this problem is to implement a variant of the 2-SUM algorithm covered in this week's lectures.

The file contains 1 million integers, both positive and negative (there might be some repetitions!).This is your array of integers, with the i^{th}i 
th
  row of the file specifying the i^{th}i 
th
  entry of the array.

Your task is to compute the number of target values tt in the interval [-10000,10000] (inclusive) such that there are distinct numbers x,yx,y in the input file that satisfy x+y=tx+y=t. (NOTE: ensuring distinctness requires a one-line addition to the algorithm from lecture.)

Write your numeric answer (an integer between 0 and 20001) in the space provided.

[sample]

-3

-1

1

2

9

11

7

6

2

and I got a right answer which is 8, but whenever I tried to compile my code with original database, it is failed.

I'm wondering if my code is wrong or my computer is wrong.

So plz if anybody could help me, let me know which is problem. :)

Thank you all.

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#define SIZE 1000000
#define MIN -10000
#define MAX 10000

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream file;
    file.open("2sum.txt");

    long long data_[SIZE];
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        file >> data_[i];
    }

    unordered_set<long long> table;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        table.insert(data_[i]);

    int count = 0;

    for (long long i = MIN; i <= MAX; i++)
    {
        cout << "for " << i << " ~~ " << endl;
        unordered_set<long long> :: iterator itr = table.begin();

        for(itr = table.begin(); itr != table.end(); itr++)
        {
            long long y = i - (*itr);
            if(table.find(y) != table.end() && (*itr) != y)
            {
                cout << "found" << endl;
                count++; break;
            }

        }
    }

    cout << count << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `whenever I tried to compile my code with original database, it is failed.` What is the compilation/run time error it shows?

Comment: @amit There isn't any mention :(

Comment: @hyungjungu It's still unclear to me what your code actually *does*.

Comment: Throwing a million 64 bit integers onto the stack can be disastrous. The default stack size for a Windows PC is only 1 MB and `data_` alone is 8 times that. There's a much larger default on your average Linux box, but you still might be pushing it. Consider using a `std::vector` to dynamically allocate from the usually much-larger Free Store.

Comment: @hyungjungu You might get one with a big try catch, but I agree with user4581301, it  looks like a stack overflow

Comment: @Ruks OMG Sorry I forgot to write what the problem was...

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks, I fixed it from array to vector and it is worked! 
Though It is really slow.. and next thing I gotta do is find more faster way :)